# What has happened

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my recent game I have found a village that is totally left behind. It is absolutely covered in cobwebs and there are no torches or coal blocks anywhere!
Can I somehow get back villagers or craft torches in other ways?

Comment: Are you even talking about Minecraft? Cobwebs don't just appear out of nowhere, they either get generated with mineshafts or get placed by players. And why would you need villages for torches?

Comment: That is an Abandoned Village, they're about a 1/50 generation chance I believe. They're known for their lack of doors or light sources, abundance of mossy cobblestone and cobwebs replacing some of the normal structure's blocks, and are populated with zombie villagers, fortunately Blacksmith buildings and crop farms are more or less unaffected. You can technically fix up the village by curing zombie villagers with a splash weakness potion and a golden apple, and you can put doors and lights back in the village yourself, but it might be better to find another village with living villagers.

Answer (score 1):

### Congratulations, you have just found a [Zombie Village!][1]

From the wiki:

```
   A village has a 2% chance of generating as a zombie village.
  In such villages, all generated villagers are instead zombie villagers, and all 
  doors and light sources are missing.
  These zombie villagers do not despawn but have no special resistance to sunlight.
  In zombie villages, some wood and cobblestone are replaced by cobwebs and mossy 
cobblestone, respectively. All glass panes are also replaced by brown stained glass panes.
```

The first time I found one, I absolutely FREAKED OUT! I thought It was Herobrine or something.
But I looked it up and it was an actual thing.
[1]: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#Zombie_villages